# terraform dereference a provider alias in for_each

Tags: terraform

Given multiple `provider`:

```
provider "aws" {
    alias  = "eu-west-1"
    region = "eu-west-1"
} 

provider "aws" { 
    alias  = "ap-northeast-1" 
    region = "ap-northeast-1" 
}
```

I have an instance definition which will load an ami based on the region.
I was wanting to assing the provider alias inside the `for_each`, but I have serious doubts this works:

```
resource "aws_instance" "test" {

  for_each = var.aws_amis
  ami = var.aws_amis[each.key]

  provider = aws.each.key  # <------ THIS LOOKS ODD; terraform init does not complain but probably will fail later...
 }
```

Looks like I can not do that...and will have to use explicit instances for every region (I just show 2 here but I was wanting several more)

Comment: in fact `terraform validate` complains about just that

Comment: This is not going to be possible in a DSL (at least none that I know of). Also, the syntax would be different for the interpolation and the method invocation for sending to the interpreter/compiler if it was possible. You will probably have to do this another way.

Comment: thank you, that was what I was assuming at this point